# Why cannot get total of the counts in R?

Tags: r, count, tidyverse

Tried to get a total Stemi only. But did not succeed. Have no clue why I cannot get it. This is in R, with tidyverse.

This is what I have tried.

```
> total_non_stringent <- zero_non_stringent %>%
+   tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(STEMI, NSTEMI), 
+                       names_to = 'type') %>%
+   group_by(type) %>% 
+   summarise(non_stringent_stemi_nstemi = sum(value))
```

And yet I got this number:

```
 non_stringent_stemi_nstemi
1                      88012
```

Yet, the answer should give me a total for stemi and a total for nstemi. Why cannot achieve it? Can someone please help? Have no clue why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, it is a case of masking from `plyr::summarise`.  Use `dplyr::summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
zero_non_stringent %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(STEMI, NSTEMI), names_to = 'type') %>%
    group_by(type) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(non_stringent_stemi_nstemi = sum(value))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  type   non_stringent_stemi_nstemi
  <chr>                       <dbl>
1 NSTEMI                      55412
2 STEMI                       32600
```

---

Or another option is to make use of [`conflicted`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/conflicted/versions/1.0.4/topics/conflict_prefer) and specify the `summarise` from `dplyr` is preferred (if `plyr` is also loaded)

```
library(conflicted)
conflict_prefer("summarise", "dplyr")
zero_non_stringent %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(STEMI, NSTEMI), names_to = 'type') %>%
    group_by(type) %>% 
    summarise(non_stringent_stemi_nstemi = sum(value))
```

Comment: and probably because of ungroup?

Comment: @GaB That wouldn't be an issue because after the pivot_longer, you are resetting the grouping by `group_by(type)`